# no se envían correos de registro wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo un sitio web donde coloque un formulario para que los usuarios se registren en un sitio wordpress con buddypress, la peticion llega a wordpress, pero el cliente no recibe sus datos de acceso. 
he probado con el formulario de registro original de buddypress y no funciona, como hacer que se envie sus datos a su correo electronico.

alguien sabe de algun codigo que permita enviar correos, he intentado con algunos y  no me funcionan.

Comment: wordpress envía los correos con la función [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) la cual intenta usar el sendmail del sistema operativo, si tu hosting no tiene sendmail, no envía los correos. hay varios plugins que extienden la función wp_mail para usar smtp o un api de webmail, si tenes un dominio en G suite que maneja tus emails el que funciona muy bien es [wp-mail-smtp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

Comment: lo que no sé es que si wordpress envía siempre en automático el correo o debo configurarlo. al haber personalizado el codigo PHP pienso algo me falta. voy a revisar esa función y espero encontrar un código que permita enviar un correo con codigo php o javascript. Gracias reviso de momento eso

Comment: ya probé con la función wp_mail y con el plugin checkmail y nada funciona!

Comment: si es así entonces es tema del hosting, puede que no tengas instalado un enviador de mail a nivel sistema operativo, tener en cuenta que algunos proveedores limitan o filtran los puertos. una opción es el plugin que te comentaba ( wp-mail-smtp ) junto a una cuenta de gmail ( normal o g suite, aunque g suite te permite manejar los mails con tu dominio ) y configurar el api en https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard

Comment: ya he logrado enviar emails desde wp_mail, al parecer un plugin era el problema